# Media Library empty or only 1 item when invoked from custom post type set featured image button

Tags: custom-post-types, media-library

Custom post type 'offer' is defined in a 'mu-plugin' using ACF syntax including featured image support. Theme functions also explicitly declare featured image support for this custom post type.

When invoked from main wp-admin sidebar menu, the media library shows multiple image items. But when invoked from custom post type set featured image button the library either claims that it's empty or it contains exactly 1 image, the one uploaded for this post.

After uploading a new image into a seemingly empty library invoked from a custom post, this image shows in that media library view, but also in the full list when invoked from the wp-admin sidebar menu.

This happens with or without using image optimization plugin like TinyPNG.

WordPress version: 6.3
Advanced Custom Fields version: 6.2.0

Code in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array(
  'post',
  'page',
  /* custom post types must also declare thumbnail support explicitly */
  'offer',
) );
```

Custom post type definition in mu-plugins:

```
        array(
          array(
            'param'    => 'post_type',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value'    => 'offer',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ) );

    /* admin column headers */
    add_filter( "manage_offer_posts_columns", function ( $defaults ) {
      $defaults['offer_position_number'] = 'Position';

      return $defaults;
    } );

    /* admin column content */
    add_action( "manage_offer_posts_custom_column", function ( $column_name, $post_id ) {
      if ( $column_name == 'offer_position_number' ) {
        echo get_field( 'offer_position_number', $post_id );
      }
    }, 10, 2 );

    /* admin column sorting headers */
    add_filter( "manage_edit-offer_sortable_columns", 'kleiderordnung_offer_sort' );
    function kleiderordnung_offer_sort( $columns ) {
      $custom = array(
        'offer_position_number' => 'offer_position_number'
      );

      return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
    }

    /* admin column sorting order by */
    add_filter( 'request', 'kleiderordnung_offer_orderby' );
    function kleiderordnung_offer_orderby( $vars ) {
      if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'offer_position_number' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
          'meta_key' => 'offer_position_number',
          'orderby'  => array(
            'offer_position_number' => 'ASC'
          )
        ) );
      }

      return $vars;
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'kleiderordnung_register_post_type_offer' );
```

Comment: Todo: verify if this correlates to custom post types or rather to multiple languages which would make it a Polylang (configuration) issue.